# Trying to update Pivot Table using Excel Visual, but get error 438. Why?

Tags: vba

`Sub TestingMacros()`
'
' TestingMacros Macro
'

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim SrcData As String
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    SrcData = sht.Name & "!" & Range("A1:R23").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create New Pivot Cache from Source Data
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)


'Change which Pivot Cache the Pivot Table is referring to
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache (pvtCache)           
End Sub
```

This last sentence `(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache (pvtCache))` has `error 438`. Cannot figure why.

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache pvtCache` 
 without the parentheses.  By wrapping it in parentheses you cause it to be *evaluated* which is likely not what you want.

Comment: Now I get a Run-time error "5": Invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestingMacros()
' TestingMacros Macro '

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim SrcRng As Range
Dim SrcData As String
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvtTbl As PivotCache

' Set the sheet obhect for the Pivot-Table data
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' set the data range for the Pivot-Table
Set SrcRng = sht.Range("A1:R23")
SrcData = SrcRng.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal) ' get the Address string with sheet reference

' Create New Pivot Cache from Source Data
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

' set the Pivot-Table object
Set pvtTbl = sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

' Change which Pivot Cache the Pivot Table is referring to
pvtTbl.ChangePivotCache pvtCache

' refresh the Pivot-Table's data
pvtTbl.RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Comment: @Woonie did you try the code in my answer above ? any feedback ?

Comment: Hello Shai,Thank you so much for helping!! Appreciate it! However, now I had Run-time error '1004': - Method "PivotTables' of object'_Worksheet failed.

Comment: @Woonie  you're welcome, now comes your part where you mark this as "Answer", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green)

Comment: Hello Shai, do you know why I have another error now? Can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Woonie you need to help a bit here, which error ? at what line ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sub TestingMacros()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim SrcData As Range

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set SrcData = sht.Range("A1:R23")

    sht.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache _
        sht.Parent.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

End Sub
```